# ASP.NET performance with PGSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, performance, postgresql

I have a c# asp.net app that connects to local databases using port forwarding. Depending on the local users upload speed this can make it really slow. Is there anyway (other than limiting the databases transactions which we are doing) of making this whole process run quicker. What database architecutre would help etc. I'm a bit of a beginner with this so i would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: The answer below is great!! The other thing that would really help if any one else cares is asp.net and html5 storage http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npgsql can do pooling -  http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html. Maybe pgBouncer helps to you. http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer

Comment: Cool that will certainly help. Does connection pooling make each transaction quicker? Is this almost as good as caching results (i imagine using the two strategies side by side is the best)